# Set cookie if domain matches

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cookies

We have a webshop at, lets say, `mywebshop.com`. For users from a specific country, lets say Germany, we have the domain `mywebshop.de`, which redirects with a 301 to `mywebshop.com`.

How can I let my .htaccess file set a cookie just before the redirect if the user navigates to `mywebshop.de` so I know at `mywebshop.com` it is a German customer? The cookie only needs to be set when navigating to `mywebshop.de`, not when navigating to `mywebshop.com`.

Eventually, some sort of paramater is also ok, but I don't know if the requested url has already some query params or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to set the cookie and do the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebshop\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mywebshop.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,CO=REDIR_DE:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]
```

If you want add a query parameter while redirecting then use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebshop\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mywebshop.com%{REQUEST_URI}?redir_de=1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: The cookie won't work (it's setting it for the original domain) but the param works fine! ty